# working with entity and repository

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

let's say that I have some IBookRepository. And besides ravendb I want to add SqlServer implementation of IBookRepository called SQLServerRepository.

What is the proper way to create implemenation of this interface having db context in mind. Should I pass dbcontext as parameter inside SQLServerRepository constructor and populate class member dbcontext to work with db?

```
public class SQLServerBookRepository : IBookRepository
{
   private MyDBContext _db;
   public SQLServerRepository(MyDBContext db)
   {
      _db = db;
   }
   public void AddBook(Book b){
      // adding book to context
      _db.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

I'm asking is this proper way? Is there are better way? Where should I store dbcontext in the same layer with repository, dao layer, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I generally manage DataContext lifetime outside of my repositories. I use my IoC tool (usually structuremap) to scope context to HttpContext. Then I simply inject an instance of my DataContext into my repositories.

Comment: does that means in general that you expecting an interface of that repository inside mvc controller and from client send an actual representation of that interface?

Comment: In general, my MVC Controller expects an interface of the repository, and I have StructureMap or Ninject (any IoC tool) provide an instance, and that IoC tool also manages the datacontext lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proper way is **not** to do this. The "Repository" pattern as an additional layer over a library that already abstracts the database is an anti-pattern.

Furthermore, the paradigms of a document database like RavenDB and a relational database are very different. You would not solve / model your solutions in the same way.

Refer to this blog post "[RavenDB and the Repository pattern](http://novuscraft.com/blog/ravendb-and-the-repository-pattern)", by a user of RavenDB who had similar intentions as you expressed, summarizing a discussion between himself and Ayende Rahien (aka Oren Eini), the creator of RavenDB.

Regarding your follow up "what if" question, related to creating a repository for EF. My advice would be the same: **don't**.

Entity Framework is already abstracting the database for you. It provides its own versions of a "Repository" as a `DbSet` and a "unit of work" as the `DbContext`. Don't put another abstraction layer over it that will always be:

1. suboptimal because now you can't access the underlying full API and
2. leaky.

Comment: thanks alex for that. If we ignore for now ravendb implementation how would you set in rough terms sqlrepository, how to communicate with db context.

Comment: I agree with @Alex in general, but I do think there are special cases where Repositories have their place.